# Html table extending off the screen

Tags: html, html-table, width

I have a table, which extends off the screen to the right (it has fixed with and this width is larger than screen width). Browser automatically creates scroll bar at the bottom. How can I instruct browser, while displaying this table in "invisible" area to the right, not to create a scroll bar? The purpose of this exercise that this table will be scrolled left using Javascript, showing its contents to the right which is initially off the screen.

---

If I set "overflow:hidden" for the "body", all other content becomes unscrollable in case it does not fit to the screen (e.g. in 1024 browser, as content is optimized for 1280). I need only this table (which is inside two DIVs) not to create browser scroll bar...

Code looks like the following way

```
<div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:1500px">
    <div style="float:left">
        <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:1500px">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:300px">
                    aaa
                </td>
                <td style="width:300px">
                    bbb
                </td>
                <td style="width:300px">
                    ccc
                </td>
                <td style="width:300px">
                    ddd
                </td>
                <td style="width:300px">
                    eee
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have another question, start a new post.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS rule:

```
body
{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** After seeing your comments, and that the `table` is within a `div` I suggest the following. Lets say your markup is:

```
<div class="tablecontainer">
  <table />
</div>
```

Use the following CSS rule:

```
div.tablecontainer
{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: If I set "overflow:hidden" for the <body>, all other content becomes unscrollable in case if does not fit to the screen (e.g. in 1024 browser, as content is optimized for 1280). I need only this table (which is inside two DIVs) not to create browser scroll bar...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`<body style="overflow-x:hidden;">`

or use any CSS class to add this property into your body tag.

Answer (score 0):

> Put an "overflow-x" styling to it. You can make the overflow hidden or give the div containing the table a horizontal scroll.

Horizontal scroll for overflow

```
<div class="col-12" style="overflow-x:scroll;">
```

Hidden overflow

```
<div class="col-12" style="overflow-x:hidden;">
```