# unable to format my table width to adjust on mobile device

Tags: html, css, blogs

I am trying to insert code blocks into my blogspot.

Here is the custom CSS i added in the blogger.com for my blog under Advanced - Add CSS section

```
#scripttable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#scripthead {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: black;
}

#scriptdata {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #00003F;
  color: white;
}
```

In the html i am using as below

```
<table id="scripttable">
<tr><th id="scripthead">Heading</th></tr>
<tr>
<td id="scriptdata">
<pre>
This is my code block to be displayed
</pre>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now i am able to get code snippet highlighted correctly when viewed on desktop but on mobile devices the table is overflowing the width of blog post.

Here is my blog which when viewed on mobile is not correct. Kindly help me know how i can fix this so that the table adjusts automatically on mobile device
https://novicejava1.blogspot.com/2020/06/how-to-build-and-deploy-python-kivy.html

Comment: Tried that link in mobile view and it looks fine

Comment: Your website is not responsive.  You have a min-width of 1200px set on your `<body>` tag and also on `.content-outer`

Comment: You also have a `meta` tag controlling your mobile view: `<meta content="width=1100" name="viewport">`

Comment: Could you let me know how i can fix it

Comment: Check out this similar question. Seems to have a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117927/html-table-extending-off-the-screen

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue of table width by updating the html content by wrapping my table in div container with style="overflow-x: auto;".

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
<table id="scripttable">
<tr><th id="scripthead">Heading</th></tr>
<tr>
<td id="scriptdata">
<pre>
This is my code block to be displayed
</pre>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Now the rendering is happening properly on mobile device after this change.